# "Undefined property: EE::$session" in ee.php after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, ee2-upgrades, sessions

After updating from v2.5.5 to v2.7.3, I get the following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: EE::$session

Filename: controllers/ee.php

Line Number: 41

Fatal error: Call to a member function userdata() on a non-object in /......../admin/expressionengine/controllers/ee.php on line 41
```

I feel like I have done this upgrade loads of times and I cannot work out where I'm going wrong here. I have overwritten all files as usual. The CP works fine.

Any ideas?!

D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, `expressionengine/controllers/ee.php` hadn't been replaced during the update, so instead of:

`class EE extends EE_Controller {`

it was

`class EE extends CI_Controller {`

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it solved :) Do mark your answer as the correct one so that your question shows as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clearing the cache (Tools > Data > Clear Caching)?

If that doesn't help - what add-ons are you using? If you try disabling them one by one, does that fix it?

Comment: Yeah I have disabled everything in my third party (even temporarily deleting everything) and cleared the cache (which is disabled in my local dev environment). I can't think what else the problem could be?

Comment: Mystery solved...